# how to get the X path for cucumber testing?

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

I tried it by right clicking on the web page and there is no xpath icon. So how can I make visible the xpath of the web page. Please reply soon. Now I am learning on cucumber automation testing. It is very important to know how to find the xpath of the web page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ChroPath to find xpath of an object. Chropath is an extension of chrome browser. It gives value of selected object. Can be seen in Developer tool only.

Answer (score 0):

The java side of this may let me down, but is there a specific reason you need the xpath rather than the css selectors?

But answering your question, if you use chrome and right click on the element you want to find the selector for. The select `inspect` at the bottom of the menu. This will open the dev tools at the bottom of your browser.

Find the element you want to target, right click that (within the dev tools) then expand the `copy` list in the menu and select copy xpath. If you look at the screenshot you can see that I can copy the xpath of the google logo
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much. I want the xpath for automation testing. Thats why I asked about it.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, Does `Copy XPath` not work for you?